# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'leftEyePosition.x') in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I don't really know where am missing it in my styles.js code. The error is: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'leftEyePosition.x'). Will I declare x and y in my function? Please I need help to solve this error. Thank you in advance for your help.
Here's my styles.js code:

```js
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    glasses: ({rightEyePosition, leftEyePosition, yawAngle, rollAngle}) => {
        const width = Math.abs(leftEyePosition.x - rightEyePosition.x) + 150;
        return {
            position: 'absolute',
            top: rightEyePosition.y - 100,
            left: rightEyePosition.x - 100,
            resizeMode: 'contain',
            width,
            transform: [{rotateX: `${yawAngle}deg`}, {rotateY: `${-rollAngle}deg`}],
        };
    },
});


export default styles;
```

Comment: It's telling you that `leftEyePosition` is undefined. Whatever's calling that `glasses` function is _not_ passing in anything meaningful.

Comment: In the component file, I called like this: <Image
                source={require('../img/glasses.png')}
                style={styles.glasses({
                    rightEyePosition,
                    leftEyePosition,
                    yawAngle,
                    rollAngle,
                })} 
            />  But, I still have not figure out why the error.

Comment: So verify your input: change `glasses({rightEyePosition, leftEyePosition, yawAngle, rollAngle}) { ... ` to `glasses(options) { console.log(options); const {rightEyePosition, leftEyePosition, yawAngle, rollAngle} = options; ... }` and verify that what you think you're putting in, is actually what you're putting in. Good bet one or more of those values are `undefined` instead of what you thought they were.